# how to create a new apex class in enterprice edition(still doubt)

Tags: salesforce

hi i got a reply from u but i checked "author apex" page even though its getting problem and also i have tried in apex IDE here also i am getting this error(i.e test coverage of selected apex trigger is 0 at least 1 % test coverage is required) while moving the apex class from developer edition to enterprice edition so kindly let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: this should of been a comment on your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a test method class that makes use of the apex trigger.  This will take care of the code coverage problem.  You then deploy the test class, and your new class at the same time.

Whenever you deploy to production, the system performs a "Run All Tests".  So, if there are any failing tests, or if there is any insufficient code coverages, your deployment will fail.